# Android Soft keyboard float only specific layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml, android-softkeyboard

I have a layout, code below

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!--some stuff here-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!--some stuff here-->
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above code  when keyboard is show i want `layout2` to stay in the `bottom` and `layout1` to `go up with keyboard`. if i add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` both layout stay in bottom. please help

Comment: please put screen shot.

Comment: @farhan latheef see my answer below I am give detail explaination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you can say this is not work

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

just change it this

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

and one more thing in your below layout

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<!--some stuff here-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <!--some stuff here-->
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Keep in Mind :

When you have applied this property `android:layout_above="@+id/layout2"` to `layout1` of your `LinearLayout` then remove this property `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` you don't require it.

So Now that look like this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

> **Note :** I am giving `background color` and `specific height` to
>   `LinearLayout 2` for your Understandment.

**Output :**

Normal Screen

[image]

KeyBoard Open Screen.

[image]

## ImProve :

[image]

see the upper Image I make `Red Mark` that property create the problem otherwise every thing is work fine.

Comment: its working,  can you add what android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" does to improve the answer

Comment: @farhanlatheef glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this, and tell me if you find any difficulties

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--some stuff here-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5" />

            <ImageButton
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!--some stuff here-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different themes for both the layouts.

such as:
One theme refers to adjustPan for windowSoftInputMode attribute.

and another theme refers to adjustResize for windowSoftInputMode attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is hide the layouts when soft keyboard is enable and show them again when the soft keyboard is disabled (`layout2` on the xml)

Remove this Line as well

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

it will work , this is just a simple way , I'm still searching for you

Answer (score 0):

put this line in your manifest file.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

And then Hide the `layout2` programmatically when soft keyboard open. When soft keyboard close, again make the `layout2` visible.

This will give user an experience exactly you want.I'm not shure there is any other way. But Keep searching. good Luck